# Multi thread or multi process to process large data by doing chunk

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a large data of 20K records or 50K records - this will be continuous process.

Am trying to chunk what ever i get data for ex: 20K records i am dividing into smaller chunks of 5K record chuck. so i get 4 chunks of data.

All 4 chunk data i need to pass into a function call and it should process parallelly because i may get one more batch of records which i need to divide to chunks and send them for parallelism.

But, it keep on loading and not processing the records as expected and continuously looping same first batch of data not stopping for chunks and pick next data of chunks

here is it what i tried,

```
def divide_chunks(l, n):
    small_msgs = []
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        small_msgs.append(l[i:i + n])
    return small_msgs

def process_data(data, i):
    #process data for chunks
    try:
        # data processing here according to my requirement
        # it may take 20-25 seconds of process that is why am planning for parallel 
          #processing
    except exceptions.BadRequest as exc:
        print(json.dumps({'error': str(exc)}))
return True

#msgs are nothing but bulk data recieving from server continuously am appending to msgs
chunk_msgs = divide_chunks(msgs, 5000)

#clearing msgs to append next data after chunking previous data
msgs.clear()

for n in range(0, len(chunk_msgs)):
    threading.Thread(target=process_data, args=(chunk_msgs[n],n)).start()
```

Comment: i juts added as place holder.. updated code @AhmedAEK

Comment: `But, it keep on loading and not processing the records as expected and continuously looping same first batch of data not stopping for chunks and pick next data of chunks` you might want to rewrite that part of the question as it is not clear, is the problem that no work is getting done at all, or that work is not getting done in parallel ? or that it is only processing the first batch in a loop ?

Comment: No half process is getting done and taking next chunk but not new set of data... this keep on continuously doing on same first time chunks and not only few lines of code processed in process_data function but full process_data is not executing for each chunk @AhmedAEK

Comment: i mean to say, if i have 3 chunks the  thread should run for 3 chunks parallelly and take next new chunks right? that;s not happening, i don't know where am doing wrong @AhmedAEK. Assalamualaikum

Comment: Your code looks alright. But once you have processed the chunks in range of chunk_msgs, the loop will end. So you don't seem to have any code that re-reruns this loop with *new* data. 
I would advice you to use futures.ProcessPoolExecutor instead of raw threads though, since your code will swamp once you generate too many threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your vague problem description i can only conclude that the problem is that work is not getting done in parallel.

threads cannot work completely in parallel due to the GIL (global interpreter lock), you should be using a process Pool instead, the process pool can do work concurrently, but it depends on what the "work" is, this is a minimal example to get it to work with a process pool.

```py
import multiprocessing

def divide_chunks(l, n):
    small_msgs = []
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        small_msgs.append(l[i:i + n])
    return small_msgs

def process_data(data, i):
    #process data for chunks
    try:
        print(data,i)
        # data processing here according to my requirement
        # it may take 20-25 seconds of process that is why am planning for parallel
        # processing
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception", e)
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":  # only imports and function/class defs before this line.
    msgs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    #msgs are nothing but bulk data recieving from server continuously am appending to msgs
    chunk_msgs = divide_chunks(msgs, 3)

    #clearing msgs to append next data after chunking previous data
    msgs.clear()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(len(chunk_msgs)) as pool:
        pool.starmap(process_data, [(chunk_msgs[n],n) for n in range(len(chunk_msgs))])
```

```
[1, 2, 3] 0
[4, 5, 6] 1
[7, 8, 9] 2
```

Comment: Let me try .. Thanks .. will comment if something i stuck

Comment: am assigning some values in if name == "main": am using in process_data method . but showing error not defined @Ahmed

Comment: @ditil you have to pass it as an argument to the function.